# Having trouble installing kubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer

Tags: boot, drivers, ati, graphics, system-installation

I having trouble install Kubuntu & Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer. The computer rebooted before it got to the desktop or any graphics (when using a CD).

I managed to install Ubuntu server edition. I installed the kubuntu-desktop on the computer. Now the computer reboots before it gets to any login screen. I think it might be because of the graphics driver.

I have a Radeon HD 4870 and I think that the graphics driver used is the open source Radeon driver.

Is there a way for me to find caused the computer to reboot?

And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you got Ubuntu server to install ok and can log in, why are using a CD for installation of kubuntu-desktop. The usual way to install kubuntu-desktop is to use a kubuntu-desktop CD and install a fresh system from there (or upgrade an existing install). Can you be more specific about what you have done and what you are now trying to do and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the system log files. You can find most of them in the /var/log directory. I would suggest you start with the boot.log and bootstrap.log files. There are also some program files in that directory. If you find a program that is suspect in a log I would then go and find the log files for that program to investigate the problem further.

The log files can be accessed either by using the file explorer or opening a terminal window and typing the following commands:

```
cd /var/log
ls
nano nameoffile.log
```

Example log file name

```
nano boot.log
```

nano is a command that opens a simple text editor for you to read the file from the terminal window. "ls" is the list function, it will list all sub-directories. "cd" is the change directory command and will allow you to move directories. I don't know if you are using a version of Ubuntu with a graphical interface or not so I included the necessary terminal commands.